# Convert date and time to GMT format

Tags: c#, datetime

I have individual calendar and time pickers. I want to combine both and convert to GMT time.

```
var time = timepicker.Time; //This is in 24hour format, but needs to store in AM,PM format
var date = calendar.SelectedDate;
string add_date_time = date+ " " +time;
DateTime gmt = add_date_time.ToUnviersalTime();
```

I get the error as

> "cannot convert string to System.DateTime"

EDIT:

this is xml code for calendar and timepicker.

```
 <controls:Calendar  x:Name="calendar"/>
 <TimePicker x:Name="time_picker" Format = "T"/>
```

After converting to gmt, I want to store in DB.

Comment: Can you edit your question to tell us the datatypes of `timepicker.Time` and `calendar.SelectedDate`, and additionally provide sample values for each. And so that it's possible to help you, please can you add your ultimate goal here?: Once you've somehow combined these, what do you intend to do with them?

Comment: You can add a date (value of type DateTime) and a time (value of type TimeSpan), which results in a new DateTime value

Comment: At a guess (I'm not familiar with the types), you want `DateTime result = (calendar.SelectedDate + timepicker.Time).ToUniversalTime()` and then you can insert that into your database.

Comment: @John yeah thats exactly what I want to do

Comment: And does it work? If you could tell me the datatypes of `SelectedDate` and `Time`, I could more than likely give you an exact answer.

Comment: selectedDate and Time are from xaml file. Above result does not work. DateTime? does not contain a definition for "ToUniversalTime"

Comment: I don't understand the XAML file. I don't know if it's built-in to WPF, UWP, a custom control, etc. because I don't use those technologies. OK. So it's datatype is `DateTime?`. What about `timepicker.Time`?

Comment: Time is of type TimeSpan. Date is DateTime

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since `calendar.SelectedDate` is a `DateTime?` and `timepicker.Time` is a `TimeSpan`, the following code should work:

```
DateTime gmt = (calendar.SelectedDate.Value + timepicker.Time).ToUniversalTime();
```

You might want to check `calendar.SelectedDate.HasValue` is `true` before running this code, in case no date is selected.

You can then use this `DateTime` value with your database access code.